# chrome.extension and $.post()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have problem with chrome.extension and jQuery Post. I want post some data (get title and url current page and send it to my DB) from `script.js` to `name.php` when I click icon.

- [Manifest.json](http://przeklej.net/file_details/15360.html)
- [script.js](http://przeklej.net/file_details/15361.html)

And in this moment I have a large problem, taburl and tabtitle don't send to `name.php` but I don't know why, so if someone can help me I'll realy happy.

BTW: sorry for any mistake language, `script.js` work on other file, but not as chrome.extension but simple code js/php. If I change `$.post` to `$.ajax` problem not disappeared.

Comment: Have you checked for errors is the background page's console? Have you used a tool like http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to see if your browser is making the web request?

Comment: Did you add it to the list of allowed domains in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script.js` is a content script. These scripts can't use `chorme.*` APIs ([source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)). Your code is never executed as it contains errors (unknown variable "chrome.browserAction"). Try using `script.js` as a background page script.

Comment: Genius :D Thx man, i just delete content_script and implement background: [script: "jquery.js", "myscript.js"], and it's run ;] I'm very greatful ;] One more time thx ! ;]